# How to prove that $\dim(\ker(T))=0$ if $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$ for $T: V \rightarrow W$

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook about Math for ML, after rank-nullity theorem, author claims without proof, that

> If $\dim(V) = \dim(W)$, then the following three-way equivalence holds:
> $\Phi$ is injective
> $\Phi$ is surjective
> $\Phi$ is bijective
> since $\mathrm{Im}(\Phi) \subseteq W$.

I dont' understand how to prove it without stating that: $$\dim(\ker(T)) = 0$$
or it could be proven from: $$\dim(V)=\dim(W)$$

Comment: What about the rank theorem?

Answer (score 0):

The rank-nullity theorem states that
$$\dim(\ker(\Phi ))+\dim(\text {im}(\Phi ))=\dim(V)$$
If $\Phi $ is injective, then $\dim(\ker(\Phi ))=0$,
$$\dim(\text {im}(\Phi ))=\dim(V)=\dim(W)\Rightarrow \text{im}(\Phi)=W$$
which proves $\Phi $ is surjective, thus bijective.

If $\Phi $ is surjective, then
$$\dim(\text {im}(\Phi ))=\dim(W)=\dim(V)$$
which proves $\dim(\ker(\Phi ))=0$, $\Phi $ is injective, thus bijective.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand statement in the textbook correctly. But I inderstand it as if dim(V) = dim(W), then some consequences are followed, and that I need to prove that mapping is injective in the first palce. Based on your explanation, statement means that if dim(V) = dim(W), then injectivity means surjectivity means bijectivity and vice versa. So I start from some point (injectivity, surjectivity or bijectivity).

Answer (score 0):

(1 implies 2) If $T$ is injective, then $\dim {\rm Ker} T = 0$. By rank-nullity, $\dim {\rm Im} T = \dim V - \dim {\rm Ker} T = \dim V$. But by hypothesis, $\dim V = \dim W$, so $\dim {\rm Im} T = \dim W$, showing that $T$ is surjective.

(2 implies 3) If $T$ is surjective, then $\dim {\rm Im} T = \dim W$. By rank-nullity, $\dim {\rm Ker} T = \dim V - \dim {\rm Im} T = \dim V - \dim W$. But by hypothesis, $\dim V = \dim W \implies \dim {\rm Ker} T = 0$, showing that $T$ is injective. Since $T$ is at once surjective and injective, $T$ is bijective.

(3 implies 1) By definition.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Phi$ is injective iff $\dim \ker \Phi = 0$ and $\Phi$ is surjective iff $\dim \operatorname{Im} \Phi = \dim W$. Under the assumption $\dim V = \dim W$, we have by rank-nullity:
$$\dim \ker \Phi + \dim \operatorname{Im} \Phi = \dim V = \dim W.$$
Rearranging,
$$\dim \ker \Phi = \dim W - \dim \operatorname{Im} \Phi.$$
So $\dim \ker \Phi = 0$ iff $\dim W - \dim \operatorname{Im} \Phi = 0$. In other words, $\Phi$ is injective iff it is surjective, so once you have one of the conditions you have both, ie $\Phi$ is bijective.